# Is there a way in Ansible to replace a dictionary value based on k:v lookup to another dictionary?

Tags: replace, ansible, jinja2, json-query

I have k:v dictionary of hostname: IP that I want to use in a lookup from another dictionary to replace entries matching key from 1st dictionary and replacing it with the corresponding value in 2nd dictionary;

1st:

```
"nb_console_ip": {
    "office-con01": "10.20.30.100",
```

2nd:

```
"nb_console_port": [
        {
            "console": "office-con01", 
            "hostname": "office-core01", 
            "port": "con1"
        }, 
        {
            "console": "office-con01", 
            "hostname": "office-core02", 
            "port": "con2"
        }, 
        {
            "console": "office-con01", 
            "hostname": "office-fw01", 
            "port": "con5"
        }, 
        {
            "console": "office-con01", 
            "hostname": "office-fw02", 
            "port": "con6"
        }, 
        {
            "console": "office-con01", 
            "hostname": "office-vpn01", 
            "port": "con3"
        }, 
        {
            "console": "office-con01", 
            "hostname": "office-vpn02", 
            "port": "con4"
        }
    ]
```

Essentially Im trying to set_fact for 2nd dict with a find and replace of `office-con01` with `10.20.30.100` but for a list of 30+ hosts.
Reason being I then have a jinja template that will use the 3 values of console_ip, hostname & port.
I was thinking maybe within there are better suited filters for lookup, find, replace etc.
Both sets of data are results of json_query on return from an API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to loop `include_tasks` and replace `k:v` in each iteration. For example, create a file with the task that replaces `outer_item.key: outer_item.value` submitted from the external loop

```
shell> cat test-task.yml
- set_fact:
    nb_console_port: "{{ nb_console_port|difference([item]) +
                         [dict(my_keys|zip(my_values2))] }}"
  vars:
    my_keys: "{{ item.keys()|list }}"
    my_values: "{{ item.values()|list }}"
    my_values2: "{{ my_values|
                   map('regex_replace', outer_item.key, outer_item.value)|
                   list }}"
  loop: "{{ nb_console_port }}"
```

Then the playbook below does the job. The variable `nb_console_port` is stored in the file `test-data.yml`

```
shell> cat test.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    nb_console_ip:
      office-con01: "10.20.30.100"
      office-con02: "10.20.30.101"
      office-con03: "10.20.30.102"

  tasks:

    - include_vars: test-data.yml

    - include_tasks: test-task.yml
      loop: "{{ nb_console_ip|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item

    - debug:
        var: nb_console_port
```

Comment: Was just trying to apply this same logic to another regex_replace but the difference in my new one is that I want to find a string and replace with an integer, but whatever way I work it it spits out: `object of type 'int' has no len()` - searching along these lines shows how Python treats strings vs. integers and advice is along lines of "convert int to str" for use - but I require int on the other end..

Comment: You might want to open a new question.

Comment: Cool, added here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671583